# How can I truncate only a single vertex of a polygon?

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

One can truncate all the vertices of a polygon at once with [`Truncate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PolyhedronOperations/ref/Truncate.html). I want to do exactly that -- but only on a single vertex. Is this possible with *Mathematica* 9? How?

Comment: I believe you will have to implement this from scratch.  You'll need to extract the points from the Polygon expression and work with the coordinates.  Have you tried doing this? If yes, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't perfectly clear what the desired scope and outcome is.  For instance, `Truncate` will close a hole created in a polyhedron.  That's not possible, if we truncate just one vertex of one polygon.  If we truncate the right ones on the right polygons, then it could be done.  The code below does not handle that case.  It's a rather special case and would need a special command to be programmed (exercise for the reader).

```
ClearAll[truncate];
Options[truncate] := {Tolerance -> 1*^-8};
truncate::nvert = "Point(s) `` not sufficiently close to a vertex are ignored.";
truncate::nidcs = "Some indices in `` are not between 1 and the number of vertices ``.";
truncate[poly : Polygon[_?MatrixQ], 
    v_Integer | v : List[___Integer] | All, ratio_: 3/10, 
    OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{vertices, n},
   n = Length@First@poly;
   If[v === All,
    vertices = Range@n,
    vertices = Flatten[{v}];
    ];
   If[vertices =!= {} && ! TrueQ[1 <= Max[vertices] <= n],
    Message[truncate::nidcs, vertices, n]
    ];
   ReplacePart[poly, 
     Function[{vi}, {1, vi} :> 
        Sequence @@ ({{ratio, 1 - ratio, 0},
                      {0, 1 - ratio, ratio}}.RotateLeft[First@poly, vi - 2][[;; 3]])
       ] /@ vertices
     ] /; vertices === {} || TrueQ[1 <= Max[vertices] <= n]
   ];
truncate[poly : Polygon[_?MatrixQ],
    v_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &) (* should check dimension - TBD *),
    ratio_: 3/10, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  With[{indices = Nearest[First@poly -> Automatic, v, {1, OptionValue[Tolerance]}]},
   If[! FreeQ[indices, {}],
    Message[truncate::nvert, Extract[v, Position[indices, {}]]]
    ];
   truncate[poly, Union @@ indices, ratio]
   ];
```

**Examples:**

Truncate two vertices by index:

```
truncate[Polygon[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, -5}}], {2, 3}]
(* Polygon[{{1, 2}, {12/5, 17/5}, {33/10, 13/10}, {37/10, -(23/10)}, {31/10, -(29/10)}}] *)
```

Truncate by specifying a point.  The code uses [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) in case a point is sufficiently close but not an exact match.  "Sufficiently close" is determined by the option `Tolerance`.  In this

```
truncate[Polygon[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, -5}}], {{2, 3}, {4.000000001, -5.}}]
```

> truncate::nvert: Point(s) {{2,3}} not sufficiently close to a vertex are ignored.

```
Polygon[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {37/10, -(23/10)}, {31/10, -(29/10)}}]
```

Graphics with [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) need to be converted to normal form. This also converts compound polygon expressions to simple polygon expressions.  If desired, there is a function in the `` NDSolve`FEM` `` context that will reassemble the polygons back into a `GraphicsComplex`.

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.2];
polys = Cases[Normal@Show@reg, _Polygon, Infinity];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Show[
 reg,
 Graphics[{Red, EdgeForm[Gray], 
   GraphicsPrimitiveToGraphicsComplex[truncate[#, 1] & /@ polys]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Truncate 3D polyhedra:

```
Normal@PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"] /. 
 p_Polygon :> {FaceForm[Red, Blue], truncate[p, 1]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I had this topic on "todo" list too :P +1